# How to replace Bundle/Argument deprecated get(key) calls in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following extension functions that allow me to pass bundle data items between my applications activities and fragments.

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Activity.extra(key: String, default: T? = null): Lazy<T?> = lazy {
    val value: Any? = intent?.extras?.get(key)
    if (value is T) value else default
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> Activity.extraNotNull(key: String, default: T? = null): Lazy<T> = lazy {
    val value: Any? = intent?.extras?.get(key)
    requireNotNull(if (value is T) value else default) { MISSING_MANDATORY_KEY + key }
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> Fragment.extra(key: String, default: T? = null): Lazy<T?> = lazy {
    val value: Any? = arguments?.get(key)
    if (value is T) value else default
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> Fragment.extraNotNull(key: String, default: T? = null): Lazy<T> = lazy {
    val value: Any? = arguments?.get(key)
    requireNotNull(if (value is T) value else default) { MISSING_MANDATORY_KEY + key }
}
```

the `.get(key)` methods are all now deprecated and i cannot see how to replace them.

as it looks as though i will need specific `.getXxxx()` calls now based on the passed data type.

what options do i have?

i like that these extension functions allow me to use one liners such as this:-

```
private val bookId by extraNotNull<Long>(EXTRA_KEY_MY_ID)

private val initialItemContentId by extraNotNull<String>(EXTRA_KEY_CONTENT_ID)
private val initialFilePath by extraNotNull<String>(EXTRA_KEYFILE_PATH)
private val initialMinPageNumber by extraNotNull<Int>(EXTRA_KEY_MIN_PAGE_NUMBER)
```

Comment: I would create an extension on every type. It still will be a one-liner and you know the type you want to get anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        url = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }

}
```

Comment: I don not want to employ this approach to retrieve the arguments, i have updated my  question