# bundle.get("pdus") as Array<*> is deprecated. What is the alternative?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My question is the same as of the title. Thanks for your solving.

`bundle?.let { bnd -> val pdus = bnd.get("pdus") as Array<*> }`
[image]

I want a new alternative code different from the `bundle.get("pdus")` method.

Comment: Have you checked its documentation? Usually a deprecation is accompanied with javadoc that explains or directs to the alternative.

Comment: Are you trying to read incoming SMS messages? If so, use [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents#getMessagesFromIntent(android.content.Intent)) instead. It will handle the PDU decoding for you, and returns an array of `SmsMessage`s. For example, `val messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)`.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73034504/how-to-replace-bundle-argument-deprecated-getkey-calls-in-android

Comment: I did a search on this topic. But I couldn't find any documentation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. I was coding to reach sms messages. And this code is totally twenty lines of code. This is a long way. But yours is the shortcut. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION) {
            val messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)
            for (message in messages) {
               val sender = message.originatingAddress
               val body = message.messageBody
            }
        }
}
```